# Constrained depth of sculpting

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, masking, layers

In **Sculpt mode**, I need to **fix Adding/Substracting** of the object to a **minimum/maximum depth**, that I've predetermined. I need the whole mesh to be smooth, as if I used normal brush but with a Layer, prohibiting me from adding or substrancting furthermore.

I've tried to:

1) Use **Layer Brush**:
I've set the Persistent Base to the desired range, but it doesn't do the trick because *a new stroke resets the depth and paints on top of the previous stroke*. There are smoothing problems as well - at the edge of the brush, where Layer ends.

[image]

2) Use **Mask Brush**:

- I've applied Solidify modifier (without the rim), then temporary hidden the outer shell and Masked the inner shell in Sculpt mode.

[image]

- The Object (with revealed outer shell) can not be substract under the masked depth, but with the radius of the brush as a minimum depth level (**outer shell still penetrates the mask**).

[image]

- Also, this method does not allow me to set a maximum depth level.

3) Is there a way to use a solidified mesh with **Mesh Analysis** to check dynamically if adding/substracting of the outer shell is out of a thickness range and then *mask* the vertices to lock them in position?

Any ideas how to improve the methods I used? A better method in mind?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be of help you.

you might use a solidify modifier to a certain seize, on a copy of your object.
Then in blender 2.82 in sculpting there is a remesh option. (top right main drawing window) this does do a voxel based remeshing of your model.
You then have a model that is a certain seize larger, thanks to that remisher it hasnt got wrong inner faces (its only the outside).

Then you can use this object in boolean operations (maybe first substract it from a cube, then use that cube shape to remove outsides from your object (ea double anti modelling).

Be aware though that boolean can have its own complexity errors (make sure to have normals recalculated outside before you start using it on all objects).